# Forming a target string using minimal substrings of words from a word list

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, search

I have a text file with first names but there are new names added every year.

I need a program in Python that takes parts of names from the text file and finds some combination of substrings of these names that can be concatenated to create a string that matches a user's input.

The program should do this using the fewest possible available names from the text file.

For example, if the text file contains this:

```
Joppe
Fien
Katrijn
Sven
Kobe
```

The program asks for a name that isn't already in the text file. For example:

```
Please fill in a name: Katrien
```

Then it should print this:

```
Katri => Katrijn
ien => Fien
```

Not like this--it builds the name correctly, but there is a better solution that uses fewer words:

```
K => Kobe
a => Katrijn
tr => Katrijn
ien => Fien
```

If the text file contains this:

```
Joppe
Fien
Makatrijn
Sven
Kobe
```

It could also print this:

```
Katr => Makatrijn
ien => Fien
```

I tried this but with no result:

```
name_input = input('Fill in a name: ')    

with open('namen.txt', 'r') as file:
    for name in file.readlines():
        for letter_name_input in name_input:
            for letter in name:
                if letter == letter_name_input:
                    print(letter)
```

Comment: If you have a question. I will be glad to answer it.

Comment: Thank you @ggorlen for making the look better, I am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: The best match is the way with as less names used as possible to make the given name.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. You input a word and the program goes through the available words from the text file to try to build the target word using as few of the available words as possible. Makes sense.

Comment: @ggorlen man... I could vaguely understand the question but I couldn't dream of wording it as well as you just did....

Comment: Exactly, this is what I meant. Sorry for my bad English it is not my mother language. And I am only 14 years old. Thanks for clarifying my question.

Comment: Your question is fine @jopw. What if two different same size, sets of words get the result? How do you decide which one is the right answer? For example if I input `a` with the names `andrew` and `alice` which name would be the correct answer?

Comment: both are fine as long as it is the same size.

Comment: I don't have the list at the moment. But if there is no way of creating the name, it can just print "Can't make the name". But this would be rare because the list has over 100+ names in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a function that takes a target name and a set of names as input, tries matching a prefix of the target name with each name in the set of names, from the longest to the shortest, and for each matching name, recursively finds the names that would form the target name with the prefix removed, from the set of names with the matching name removed, and yields each of the returning combinations with the current prefix and name prepended as a tuple:

```
def form_name(target, names):
    if target:
        for i in range(len(target), 0, -1):
            prefix = target[:i]
            matching_names = [name for name in names if prefix.lower() in name.lower()]
            if matching_names:
                for name in matching_names:
                    for fragments in form_name(target[i:], names - {name}):
                        yield [(prefix, name), *fragments]
    else:
        yield []
```

so that you can use the `min` function with `len` as the key function to obtain the combination with the fewest names:

```
from io import StringIO
file = StringIO('''Joppe
Fien
Katrijn
Sven
Kobe''')
for fragment, name in min(form_name('Katrien', set(file.read().split())), key=len):
    print(fragment, '=>', name)
```

outputs:

```
Katri => Katrijn
en => Fien
```

Demo: https://repl.it/repls/IllustriousTrustingIntegrationtesting

Note that both `Fien` and `Sven` in your example input would match the `en` fragment and make for valid answers with the fewest names, so the `min` function would arbitrarily return one of them (which is fine per your requirement). Also note that you shouldn't expect the fragments of the target name to overlap, so instead of `ien` the second fragment should be `en` after the first fragment `Katri` is removed from the target name `Katrien`.

If you're interested in seeing all the valid answers, you can calculate the minimum length of all the combinations first and then output all the combinations with the minimum length:

```
combinations = list(form_name('Katrien', set(file.read().split())))
min_len = min(map(len, combinations))
for combination in combinations:
    if len(combination) == min_len:
        for fragment, name in combination:
            print(fragment, '=>', name)
        print()
```

This outputs:

```
Katri => Katrijn
en => Sven

Katri => Katrijn
en => Fien

Katr => Katrijn
ien => Fien
```

Comment: This works flawless. Thank you so much. This will be used for real stuff. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you'd want to stop searching as soon as you find a shortest answer, here's my solution:

First you need a function to break the word into all possible parts starting from the biggest possible set:

```
def breakWord(word, n):
  list = []
  for k in range(len(word)):
    subword = word[k:]
    out = [(subword[i:i+n]) for i in range(0, len(subword), n)] 
    if(k > 0): 
      out.append(word[:k])
    list.append(out)
  return list
```

Notice that if you use:

```
breakWord(yourWord, len(yourWord)-1)
```

It will break the word into all possible sets of two parts.
Then a function to check if a given string is in the list of names:

```
def isInNames(word):
  for name in name_list:
    if(word in name):
      return true
  return false
```

Finally iterate over the whole possible combination of characters:

```
def findWordCombination(word):
  resultSet = []
  resultSize = 50  #Something large to ensure it gets changed
  for i in range(len(word)-1, 0, -1): #Will go from max to     minimum
    testSet = breakWord(word, i)
    for set in testSet:
      isValid = true #assumes true at first
      for part in set:
        if(not isInNames(part)):
          isValid = false
      #Once all parts of the set are checked we find
      #If the set is valid. i.e. it is a valid combination.
      if(isValid and len(set) < resultSize):
        resultSize = len(set)
        resultList = set
  return resultList
```

This will return the first set that finds with the minimum possible combination of subwords from your search query. You can tweak it to have it store the words names from the list that yielded the resulting set.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach (I upvoted @blhsing's recursive solution already, very elegant, I love it)

```
import itertools as it
from collections import defaultdict


def get_all_substrings(input_string):
  length = len(input_string)
  return [input_string[i:j+1] for i in range(length) for j in range(i,length)]

names = ['Joppe', 'Fien', 'Katrijn', 'Sven', 'Kobe']
d = defaultdict(list)  # each key is a substring of any of the names and the value is the list of names that contain it
for name in names:
    for subname in get_all_substrings(name):
        d[subname].append(name)

input_name  = 'Katrien'
input_subs = get_all_substrings(input_name)

sub_combs = [it.combinations(input_subs, n) for n in range(1,len(input_name))]
whole_combs = [el for co in sub_combs for el in co if ''.join(el) == input_name]  # those combs that can form the input name

saved = [wc for wc in whole_combs if all((c in d for c in wc))]  # those whole combinations that actually appear

shortest_comb = min(saved, key=len)

shortest_sub_and_name = [(s, d[s]) for s in shortest_comb]
for s, ns in shortest_sub_and_name:
    print(f"{s} => {ns}")
```

produces

```
Katr => ['Katrijn']
ien => ['Fien']
```

Note: as you can see, the output shows all the names that can contribute to each specific substring

Comment: Your solution works too. It even prints multiple names when there are multiple solutions. For example: input_name = 'Koen' result: Ko => ['Kobe'] en => ['Fien', 'Sven'] so it prints both names cause they are both the right answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
import difflib

name = input('Please fill in a name: ')

with open('namen.txt', 'r') as file:
  file_data = file.readlines()
  # either you are looking for
  print([i for i in file_data if difflib.SequenceMatcher(a = i,b = name).ratio() >= 0.5])
  #or you are looking for
  print(difflib.get_close_matches(name,file_data,len(file_data),0.5))
['Katrijn\n', 'Fien\n']
```

Comment: `print(difflib.get_close_matches(d,c,len(c),0.5))`. This gives the error d,c not defined. `print([i for i in file_data if difflib.SequenceMatcher(a = i,b = name).ratio() >= 0.5])` this one kinda works but when I fill in for example` Koen` it prints `Kobe` because it thinks that it can switch letters in the name.

Comment: @jopw you can play with the ratio the default is 0.6 That is where the two strings are considered to match. Below that, the two are not considered to match. But I just used 0.5 to give you the desired output even though I know the two are not close

Comment: When i try `Koen` with `print(difflib.get_close_matches(name,file_data,len(file_data),0.5))`i get this as a result `Please fill in a name: Koen
['Kobe']` this is not right because you can only take parts of the name not switch the letters.

Comment: `difflib` is really cool, but I don't think this produces anything resembling the desired output. The OP isn't looking for approximate matches, OP is looking for a minimal series of words that contain substrings that can be concatenated to build the target word.

Comment: I will be able to reply tomorrow.

Comment: @jopw the letters are not switched. The `Levenshtein distance` is computed between the two strings. when a  letter does not match, it jumps to the next. It does not switch them